# In SQL, how do I write a "IN" statement for string?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So the IN operator is quite useful to search for integer with multiple criteria:

```
ID in (1,2,3,4)
```

How do I do this for string field?

```
ID like ('A','B','C','D')
```

Comment: `ID IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')`?

Comment: Oh... ok, didn't know IN works on String

Comment: you have it right in your question, just `ID like ('a', 'b',...'nth')`

Comment: You need to check if the first letter is A, B, C or D ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For integer values :

```
ID in (1,2,3,4)
```

For character values :

```
ID IN ('A','B','C','D')
```

Comment: You are right, I should have really just checked IN works for string too.